# Convert RDS into R file

Tags: r

I had a .rds file code which im told it is a file with R codes. I tried to access it by using `readRDS` and is able to view the output. May I know how can I convert the .rds into .r file or any editable format so that I could make some edits and view the codes? I have tried looking for solutions but I could not find any related ones.

Link to the .rds file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGgKA1ejkF7_uq_27E6Qpaq_fdAcDL8O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: RDS files contain data, not code. What you were told is wrong.

Comment: @Roland actually, rds can contain  any object including functions and expressions

Comment: @dww Of course. However, someone who saves "code" in an RDS file is unlikely to have used pure functional programming or to have saved expressions in an environment. They are much more likely to have thought they would save their script that way. So maybe my statement needs to be qualified but I would be surprised if that helps OP at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rds file contains R code, rather than data (which it can, because rds format can save any object including functions and expressions)...  then, we can use `dput` to export the contents into a human readable format.

Here's a simple example:

```
hello = function() {
  print("Hello world")
}

saveRDS(hello, 'hello.rds')

dput(readRDS('hello.rds'), file='hello.r')
```

The file `hello.r` now contains the following:

```
function () 
{
    print("Hello world")
}
```

If we do the same thing with your original file (i.e., `dput(readRDS('Fundamental_Model.rds'), file='hello.r')`), we get:

```
list(Fundamental_Model = structure(list(handle = <pointer: (nil)>, 
    raw = as.raw(c(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 

# ... many lines omitted

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6e, 0x69, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x03, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x31, 0x32, 0x38)), niter = 129, 
    call = xgb.train(data = df_train, nrounds = best.nrounds, 
        paras = xgb.params), params = list(paras = list(colsample_bytree = 0.85, 
        subsample = 0.85, booster = "gbtree", max_depth = 6, 
        eta = 0.03, eval_metric = "rmse", objective = "reg:linear", 
        gamma = 0), silent = 1), callbacks = list(cb.print.evaluation = structure(function (env = parent.frame()) 
    {
        if (length(env$bst_evaluation) == 0 || period == 0 || 
            NVL(env$rank, 0) != 0) 
            return()
        i <- env$iteration
        if ((i - 1)%%period == 0 || i == env$begin_iteration || 
            i == env$end_iteration) {
            stdev <- if (showsd) 
                env$bst_evaluation_err
            else NULL
            msg <- format.eval.string(i, env$bst_evaluation, 
                stdev)
            cat(msg, "\n")
        }
    }, call = cb.print.evaluation(period = print_every_n), name = "cb.print.evaluation")), 
    feature_names = c("X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", 
    "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16"), nfeatures = 11L), class = "xgb.Booster"))
```